# Can we construct $\Bbb C$ without first identifying $\Bbb R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Sometimes it is useful to consider $\Bbb C$ as our primitive and identify $\Bbb R$ as a subset of $\Bbb C$.  Thus we can define $\Bbb R$ (or at least a set with all of the interesting properties of $\Bbb R$) from $\Bbb C$.

This suggests to me that there is some way of constructing $\Bbb C$ *without* first constructing (or taking as a primitive) $\Bbb R$.  However, I've never seen such a construction of $\Bbb C$ (a quick Google search didn't provide me one, either).  I've the Cayley-Dickson construction and the matrix construction many times, but are they the only known ways of constructing $\Bbb C$?

My question:

> Is there a way to construct the set of complex numbers without already having (or first constructing) the real numbers?

Comment: Would the closure of $\Bbb Q$ give you $\Bbb C$ or some proper subset of $\Bbb C$?

Comment: The simplest thing you can do is take the (metric) completion of the field $ℚ(i)$.

Comment: Next, the metric closure of $ \bar {\mathbb Q},$ equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences, is $\mathbb C$

Comment: ...in particular, the answer is yes: first construct $\bar{\mathbb Q}$, then take trans. extension of size continuum.

Comment: @Will How do you define a metic on an abstract alg. closure of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @Grigory, I suppose I don't know.

Comment: @Grigory, two new answers saying take the metric closure of $\mathbb Q(i),$ I think that works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to avoid $\Bbb R$ and just use general machinery, one way to do it is to use $\Bbb Q(i)$ or any finite extension of $\Bbb Q$ which has zero real embeddings. You can ensure this by taking the extension to be cyclotomic, for example. Then you know there is a norm on the vector space $\Bbb Q(i)$ given by

$$\lVert a+bi\rVert=|a|+|b|.$$

It's easily verified that it is archimedean--this is handy because it will give you a copy of $\Bbb R$ as a subset when you're finished making $\Bbb C$. Now, you can verify that addition, subtraction, multiplication, and inversion of non-zero elements is **continuous** so that you have a topological field.

Then by forming the metric completion and declaring it to be $\Bbb C$, you automatically have that this is a field because of continuity of the field operations. It is not otherwise obvious that your set of equivalence classes should form such a thing.

Comment: Similar to the comment on the other answer: what is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ when you don't have $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki this is a minor point of modifying the norm. Since the space is finite dimensional, they're all equivalent (i.e. induce the same topology for convergence). I've edited the answer. Take a look to see one straightforward means of avoiding it.

Comment: Yep, that makes perfect sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: What is a norm if we can't use the reals?

Comment: @JakobWerner, if you have access to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ then you can make sense of norms etc. You don't need the whole real line.

Comment: @JakobWerner it still formally satisfies all the properties, just pretend you're using $\Bbb Q_{\ge 0}$ which is perfectly well defined and functions just as it should.

Answer (score 4):

Any algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$ having the same cardinality as $\mathbb C$ is isomorphic (non-canonically) to $\mathbb C$. This allows one to construct a lot of fields which are abstractly isomorphic to $\mathbb C$ without ever looking at the real numbers.

For example, the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb C$. However, no isomorphism between them is continuous, so this is not very interesting if you're interested in $\mathbb C$ as a topological field.

Comment: How can we identify $ \mathbb {R} $ in $\mathbb {Q}_p $?

Comment: @Jakob It's not true that $\mathbb R$ embeds in $\mathbb Q_p$, but it does embed in the algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q_p$ (very non-canonically and non-continuously). You cannot really write down the embedding without using the axiom of choice, as far as I know.

Comment: Ah, I misread that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: start with the commutative semiring $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}.$ Write:

1. $\mathbf{CSem}$ for the category of commutative semirings
2. $\mathbf{CRing}$ for the category of commutative semirings with a distinguished element $(-1)$ such that $(-1)+1=0$, also known as the category of commutative rings.
3. $\mathbf{CRing}[i]$ for the category of commutative semirings with a distinguished element $i$ such that $i^2+1=0$.

(All my semirings have a $0$ and a $1$.)

Now there is a forgetful functor $U_\mathrm{I} : \mathbf{CRing} \rightarrow \mathbf{CSem}$ and another $U_\mathrm{II} : \mathbf{CRing}[i] \rightarrow \mathbf{CSem}$. Both have left adjoints. Just like $\mathbb{R}$ is the image of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ under the left-adjoint to $U_\mathrm{I}$, similarly $\mathbb{C}$ is the image of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ under the left-adjoint to $U_\mathrm{II}$.

(You should check that the details play out as expected, since I have not.)